# Hadoop Unable to Find Mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I get `ClassNotFoundException` when I run my Hadoop job (new API - 1.0.3).
I have a `Main` class that contains static `MapClass` and `ReduceClass` as nested classes.

I configure my job as follows:

```
    Job job = new Job();

    job.setJarByClass(Main.class);
    job.setJobName("My Job");

    job.setMapperClass(Main.MapClass.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Main.ReduceClass.class);
```

Main class is as follows:

```
public class Main {
    //Nested static Mapper
public static class MapClass extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    @Override
    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) {
            ...
    }
}

    // Nested static Reducer
public static class ReduceClass extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I did not export jar from the project as Eclipse creates `Main.class`, `Main$MapClass.class` and `Main$ReduceClass.class` files inside the `bin` directory of the project folder, which I think should be part of classpath.
However the job is unable to find the Mapper class:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MapClass
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:867)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:719)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: @Razvan: I run my job from Eclipse - Cntr + F11

Comment: run it using the hadoop script in the /bin dir of your Hadoop installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exporting a jar file of your project. Then use this jar in the following command:

```
hadoop jar "jar name" package.subpackage.DriverClass [-conf configXML] 
inputDir outputDir
```

The Driver class is the MainClass. The conf option is optional but recommended and it specifies a file where you set specific configuration options.

Comment: That works. If I export the Eclipse project as a jar and add it back to the project as an external jar, the program runs. However `Main.class`, `Main$MapClass.class` and `Main$ReduceClass.class` files are sitting in `bin` folder of Eclipse project, why does it not pick it from there? And when I tried adding this `bin` folder as an external library, the program gave the same exception. Looks like adding jar is the only option working.

Comment: Because you say this: job.setJarByClass(Main.class);
And there is no such jar

Answer (score 0):

If you are running as a Java application in Eclipse, Eclipse doesn't ship all the needed files i.e. `Mapper` and `Reducer` to Hadoop. Use Eclipse Plugin for Hadoop to run applications directly in Hadoop from Eclipse.